# OpenCV Version Issue

Tags: opencv, anaconda

How to check the current version of OpenCV for mac and how to update my version to the newest version? I am trying to use the drawMatchesKNN and drawMatches function. The error I get is something like name 'drawMatches' is not defined". What I know is that I don't have the right version of OpenCV. But I don't know how to check my openCV version and update it to the newest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Python, run below code will get the OpenCV version:

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__

3.2.0
```

3.2.0 is the latest one. As for upgrade on macOS, if you are using Anaconda, it would be easier. You may refer to this [page](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?Email=ivanchanbsc@gmail.com&continue=https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?rfn%3D27%26rfnc%3D1%26et%3D0%26asae%3D2) to get some more information. For draw matching and related functions, seems you need to have `opencv_contrib` modules (I haven't checked at the time being).

**EDIT:**

The [Anaconda repository](https://anaconda.org/) has two channels with `OpenCV 3.2.0` available.

You may try `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0`. This `menpo` repository does have `OpenCV 3.2.0` for `Python 2.7/3.4/3.5` and for `linux-64`.

The `conda-forge` repository, `conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0`,  has many difference version of binary on `OpenCV 3.2`. You may have a trial this `conda-forge` if the `menpo` package doesn't work. You can check its [file page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) on the binary available.

To uninstall the conda package, just type `conda uninstall opencv3` for `OpenCV 3.x`.

Before installing `OpenCV 3.x`, it would be better to uninstall your `OpenCV 2.4.8` to avoid conflict. You may try `conda uninstall opencv` for `OpenCV 2.x` or find out the package name by `conda list`.

As for the OSX, what are the version you are using?

Comment: Thank you! I checked my openCV version with your code successfully. Mine is 2.4.8  I am wondering what does the page link to? After I clicked hyperlink, there is a login page for my google account.

Comment: I found out that I installed openCV through Anaconda. Do you know how to update the openCV version using Anaconda?

Comment: @ thewaywewere Thank you so much for your answer. I used `conda install -c menpo opencv3` to create a virtual environment and it works. My reputation for Stackoverflow is less than 15. So even though I click the vote, the number will not change. I will vote your answer when I get 3 more reputation.

Comment: @Judie You are welcome. Glad to hear you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you installed it. If you use **homebrew** and you did:

```
brew install opencv
```

then, you can get your version with:

```
brew info opencv
```

and you can get the latest version with:

```
brew upgrade opencv
```

---

If you did:

```
brew install opencv3
```

then you need to do:

```
brew info opencv3
```

and you can upgrade with:

```
brew upgrade opencv3
```

---

If you cloned the git repo on github, you need to go to your build directory and run:

```
more *tmp
```

and you can upgrade with:

```
cd /where/ever/you/cloned/opencv
git pull
cd /where/ever/you/built/opencv
cmake /where/ever/you/cloned/opencv
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

Failing all that, build a simple executable that calls  `getBuildInformation()`

Comment: Thank you! It seems like that I did not use both of the ways you listed. What do you mean by building a simple executable that calls getBuildInformation()?