# What is the deal with `pip install opencv-python` is it a full opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I thought the quickest way to get opencv running in my environment would be as simple as.

```
sudo pip install opencv-python
```

It seemed to work properly, I could import

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("a.jpg", 0)
```

but any other functions as "cv2.SURF" or even "cv2.imshow" are not loaded. So the pip install is giving just a basic opencv?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843316/solved-how-to-include-libgtk2-0-dev-and-pkg-config-in-cmake-when-installing?noredirect=1#comment72858371_42843316)
Opencv-python is not official. I tried to install it in a macbook running Ubuntu and, as you, I could import cv2, but  some functions were not working.

From the opencv-python website:

> MacOS and Linux wheels have some limitations:
>
> video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with
>   FFmpeg) for example cv.imshow() will not work (not compiled with GTK+
>   2.x or Carbon support)

Now you might have problems trying to install the official opencv. You have to completely uninstall opencv-python before you attempt to install opencv.

Answer (score 1):

This post is aging. I have Anaconda, and I have installed OpenCV as

```
conda install -c- conda-forge ffmpeg
pip install opencv-python
```

Maybe opencv-python had problems before, but now, is funcional

Answer (score 0):

In the [OpenCV docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), it is mentioned that `sudo pip install opencv-python` is an **unofficial** package for python. 
Quote : *This package contains only the OpenCV core modules without the optional contrib modules.*

It is meant for *OpenCV Python bindings only*. Additionally, some functions still don't work for MacOS and Linux (`cv2.imshow` as you mentioned).

If you want the full installation, follow the steps [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Is there any evidence, that this was tested on mac?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to install Anaconda and use its package manager `conda` to install `OpenCV 3.2.0` for `linux-64`, including `OSX`. The installation command is `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0`.

Checked the OpenCV 3.2.0 package available in Anaconda repository. It includes the `features2d.so` which is the extra module in `opencv_contrib` for supporting SIRF.

See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238064/opencv-version-issue/43239634#43239634) for some more information.