# OpenCV python on MAC

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pycharm

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('mikrotik.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## I ran this code on my Pycharm on mac machine

then get this error instead

```
>/Users/briant/venv/bin/python /Users/briant/PycharmProjects/InputandOutput/ImageTestFile.py
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu >or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or >configure script) in cvShowImage, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv->python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
    >Traceback (most recent call last):
    >  File "/Users/briant/PycharmProjects/InputandOutput/ImageTestFile.py", >line 9, in <module>
    >    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    >cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv->python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function >is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon >support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg->config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage


>Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone please explain to me, what am I supposed to do?
thank you in advance.

Comment: follow this http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Comment: The message is clear: **If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg->config**

Comment: Rebuild your opencv. If you don't plan to use C++, build it with `brew opencv3 --with-python`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I already do that, but it returned me this kind of error: 
`Last login: Mon Apr 17 15:55:52 on ttys000
Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew opencv3 --with-python
Error: Unknown command: opencv3
Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew opencv --with-python
Error: Unknown command: opencv
Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew opencv2 --with-python
Error: Unknown command: opencv2
Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ `

Comment: my bad, it should be `brew install opencv3 --with-python`. Note the `install` command. Also it should be `opencv3` as `opencv2` is not actively developed anymore.

Comment: @QuangHoang I got this message instead:

`Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew install python
Warning: python-2.7.13 already installed, it's just not linked.`

and get this instead with your latest comment:
`Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew install opencv3 --with-python
Warning: homebrew/science/opencv3 is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version`

Comment: Yes, and I would then link pyCharm's interpreter to brew's python. Also, if you want to use python3, you would need `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`.

Comment: `Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ brew install opencv3 --with-python3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.`

>`Warning: homebrew/science/opencv3 is a keg-only and another version is >linked to opt.
>Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
>Briants-MacBook-Pro:~ briant$ `

should I type `brew install --force` ? @QuangHoang

Comment: Suggest to try [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) if the problem is still not able to solve in 30 mins. Anaconda's Python package manager 'conda' would help to download the dependent packages to ease the installation. You may refer this [OS answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238064/opencv-version-issue/43239634#43239634) for some more information. Once Anaconda is installed, may take 10 mins, then type `install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0` to install `OpenCV`.